# How to exclude port number from RSS hashing for tcp4 with ixgbe

Tags: linux-device-driver

In the README for ixgbe driver there is section about configuring RSS hashing algorithm:

> -N --config-nfc
>         Configures the receive network flow classification.
>
> rx-flow-hash tcp4|udp4|ah4|esp4|sctp4|tcp6|udp6|ah6|esp6|sctp6
>   m|v|t|s|d|f|n|r...
>
> - To exclude UDP port numbers from RSS hashing run: 
>       ethtool -N ethX rx-flow-hash udp4 sd

For excluding port from hashing algorithm for udp4 all working well. But when I try to make same for tcp4, it fail:

```
~# ethtool -N eth2 rx-flow-hash tcp4 sd
Cannot change RX network flow hashing options: Invalid argument
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that error once, when I forgot to bring up the interface before running the ethtool command. So run:

```
ifconfig eth2 up
```

Then check to see if that solves the problem. I have seen a couple of cases where the problem was not resolved this way, but I recommend trying it first and then run the command again to see if that solves your problem.